# zsh: illegal hardware instruction npm run start-server

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, apple-m1

Goal : To build a **Node.js** web server for a training and classification model on the server-side using **TensorFlow.js**
I am trying to do [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/training/nodejs_training) to learn TensorFlow.js.

Expected results : Server should run locally on an appropriate port like so.

```
$ npm run start-server
...
  > Running socket on port: 8001
Epoch 1 / 1
eta=0.0 ========================================================================================================>
2432ms 34741us/step - acc=0.429 loss=1.49
```

Actual results : Server does not run

```
@MacBook-Pro baseball % npm run start-server

> tfjs-examples-baseball-node@0.2.0 start-server
> node server.js

zsh: illegal hardware instruction  npm run start-server
```

My hardware and software configuration :

- MacBook Pro (13 inches, M1, 2020)
- Chip : Apple M1
- macOS Big Sur version 11.4
- @tensorflow/tfjs-node: ^1.3.2
- Node.js version : v14.17.5
- Xcode 12.5.1 / Build version 12E507

What have I tried ?
At this stage, I can't remember the number of Github issues and Stackoverflow question I have read to solve this problem without success.

1. Tried using prior versions of @tensorflow/tfjs-node like 1.2.0 and 1.0.0.
2. Tried the most recent version of @tensorflow/tfjs-node i.e. 3.8.0
3. Checked if Python 2.7.16 and 3.9.6 are installed on my Mac. They are.
4. Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and ran npm install
5. Updated Node.js to its most recent version.
6. Made sure Xcode is installed.

It seems to be a hardware compatibility issue but I can't figure out the solution. Please note that I am trying to use the **Javascript** implementation of TensorFlow and not Python.

Comment: Did you tried with `Rosetta2` enabled terminal?

Comment: have you solved this prob? I am running into the same problem

Comment: Not yet. At the moment, I am caught up with other urgent issues.

Answer (score 0):

first, `tfjs-node` includes binary `tensorflow` implementation (same on as python), the JS part is just a wrapper (tfjs-node installer actually builds NAPI bindings to the binary)

second, this is M1 CPU which doesn't emulates x86 instruction set - and advanced instructions (e.g. AVX) are simply not supported.

since you've already tried old `tfjs-node` v1.2 (last one before AVX), only proper solution is to build `tfjs-node` from scratch on M1 hardware - quite a painful process, but not impossible

you might get lucky if you search on github for someone else's port

**UPDATE:**

Apple has created a fork of TF that uses Apple's ML libs based on TF 2.4RC (and optionally `Metal` libs),
but it doesn't seem well maintained - last update is in March 2021.

- https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos
- https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

So first step is to get TF working in Python
then it's a question of rebuilding `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` package to use that library instead of prebundled one

Comment: Hey, I am using `"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^3.9.0",` this and just trying to do exactly https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers this thing. I face the the same problem. I updated npm, node and everything. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've updated the answer - still far from ideal, but could be worth a try

Comment: I’d decided to learn python lol

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you are using Mac or Linux,

- remove node from everywhere, from every package manager,
- if brew, use `brew uninstall node`
- install Node.JS from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

And then try `npm start` or anything you wish.

This is how my issues are gone. Hope that it'll fix this issues from your sides too. Thanks.